# Does $f_{n}(x)=\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}$ converge pointwise / uniformly?

Tags: analysis

Since our lectures were cancelled because of the ongoing situation, I have to essentially self-study for my analysis exam in two months. Understandably this comes with a great deal of trouble, so I would like someone to help me with the following question:

**Question:** Show that $f_{n} : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $f_{n}(x):=\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}$ pointwise converges on $\mathbb{R}$. Examine whether it uniformly converges on $I=[0,2]$, $J=[2,\infty)$.

**Pointwise convergence:** From what I've understood so far, I have to show $\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x) = f(x)$ for every $x$ to prove it. This is my solution:

$lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}=lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x^{2n}}+1}$

$f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x) =\begin{cases}0 &if& |x|<1\\\frac{1}{2} & if&|x| = 1\\1&if&|x|>1\end{cases}$

**Uniform convergence:**
Here, I can show that:

$\big|~f_n(x) - f(x)~\big| = \displaystyle 
\begin{cases}\displaystyle\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}  & \text{if }~ |x|<1\\ 
0 &\text{if } |x|=1\\
\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}-1  &\text{if } |x|>1
\end{cases} $

Since $\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}-1$ = $\frac{-1}{1+x^{2n}}$ it would be equal to $0$ for $|x|>1$ as well.
This would mean that this function does indeed uniformly converge on $J=[2,\infty)$.
On the other hand, $f_{n}(x)$  doesn't converge uniformly on $I=[0,2]$ since it converges to a discontinuous function on this interval.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument for $x>2%=$ is not at all clear. A complete proof would be to say that $|f_n(x)-1|=\frac 1 {1+x^{2n}} \leq \frac  1 {x^{2n}} \leq \frac 1 {2^{2n}}$ for all $x>2$ and hence  $sup_{x >2}|f_n(x)-1| \to 0$.

Comment: Thank you for answer! I assume the rest of my answer is correct?

Comment: Yes, the rest is correct. @Ayushi